# Realtek Audio not switching to headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I recently upgraded to Win 10 and most things are going great, the only problem I have however is that when I plug in my headphones into the computer it doesn't auto switch to them and the audio still plays our of my monitor.  I have to right click on the audio >select playback devices> set headphones as default or the reverse to change back. I have updated all my drivers including the Realtek.

Asus 990fx R2.0 sabertooth MB
EVGA Geforce GTX 750 ti graphics card
Lenova LI2821 4k hooked up through display port
Realtek HD Audio Manager

Comment: When you updated the Realtek drivers, did you get them from MS, Asus or Realtek?

Comment: This may or may not solve your issue but here it is. There used to be a setting in Realtek Audio Manager that when applied wouldn't switch my laptop speakers off, even if I plugged in my headphone. Maybe, you should check such settings there.